# How to convert an unsigned long long with leading zeroes to string?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a function that should take as parameter an unsigned long long in the hex format. I am trying to convert this parameter to a string to check if it is made of 16 digits or not, but I am having problems with leading zeros

```
template <typename T>
static string to_string(const T& value) {
stringstream oss;
oss << hex << setprecision(16) << value;
return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    unsigned long long pattern1 = 0x0000001000000002;
    unsigned long long pattern2 = 0x0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    cout << "Pattern 1 = " << to_string(pattern1) << endl;
    cout << "Pattern 2 = " << to_string(pattern2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What I want is for the pattern 1 to be converted with the zeroes to be able to check its length but this is the output. I tried using the set precision but didn't seem to help

```
Pattern 1 = 1000000002
Pattern 2 = ffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Impossible. The number of leading zeroes in memory is determined by the size of the type.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. How many leading zeroes do you want to add to the string?

Comment: @melpomene I don't want to add zeroes, I just want to check for the length of the `unsigned long long` when it is in a hex format

Comment: *Any* `unsigned long long` is going to have 16 hex digits in the compiler you are using. You don't need to check its length. The compiler will ensure your method receives an `unsigned long long` if that is the signature of the parameter. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The number of decimal digits *without* the leading zeros is given by `log10(value)+1`. No string conversion required. But that's not what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know the number of the digits that was *"entered by the user"* except if you already read it through an "array" (`char*`, `std::string`, ...).

If you have an `unsigned long long`, the variable size will be `8` bytes anyway:

```
unsigned long long a = 0x1; // This will internally be: 0x0000000000000001
```

---

Now, if you want to get back the leading zeros from the actual type in the `std::string`, I think the following should do the trick (as already mentioned by other answers):

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T & val)
{
    std::stringstream oss;
    oss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T)*2) << val;
    return oss.str();
}
```

But perhaps it could be better to overload the function for any integral types you want to use instead of using a `template`.
Because if someone calls the function with a type that is not a `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` (resp. `unsigned`), the function will be broken.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how many characters should be in a number? The count of leading zeros can be infinite. I think this helps you

```
int character_count = 10;
oss << hex << setfill('0') << setw(character_count) << value;
```

Comment: This will change the size of pattern1 to be equal to `character_count`. Where what I want is count how many digits did the user enter. In your case `0x0010002` will be printed out as `0000010002`

Comment: @HasanH As your question stands, the "user" entered no digits at all.

Comment: @YSC Assuming that pattern1 is a parameter in some function and I want to check the size of it with its leading zeroes.

Comment: If you want know how many digits did the user enter, than you must read it in string or char*, because long long does not store info about leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The length of an `unsigned long long` represented as an hexadecimal number, including leading zeros, is:

```
sizeof(unsigned long long)*2
```

Since we are including leading zeros, the value of the `unsigned long long` is not relevant.